# transcribing common error help needed to do

Tags: passive-voice

What does this man says in this file?
http://s0.vocaroo.com/media/download_temp/Vocaroo_s0i1JjqEqFg5.mp3
He says `make sure that your back stays .......(what?)....... with the floor, your head should be up ...`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU is not a transcription service

Comment: @FumbleFingers can you suggest me a transcription service to use instead of ELU?

Comment: There are lots of paid-for services - in fact, everything on the first couple of pages returned by googling ***free** english transcription service* seems to be commercial offerings. It's not obvious to me why any company would offer such things free, nor can I see how they'd persuade large numbers of native speakers to devote their time to supporting such a service if they're not getting paid. If you *do* find anything free, be aware you might be getting poor quality guidance from non-native speakers trying to improve their *own* command of English through such channels.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This world sucks! Anyway do what you want ;)

Comment: Is that your normal response when people don't drop everything they're doing to attend to your wishes? Off you go, now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The speaker says **parallel** to the floor. He slurs his speech, but the context makes it clear he is explaining an exercise (such as a sit-up or abdominal crunch) that requires keeping the back flat.

Here is a different exercise that asks for the same parallel form:

> The Bird Dog, also known as the quadraplex, is a more complicated stationary exercise, working many muscle groups simultaneously for a powerful core workout. Start on your hands and knees, with your palms flat, shoulder-width apart, and **your back parallel to the floor**. - [LiveStrong.com Abdominal Exercises](http://www.livestrong.com/article/513963-abdominal-muscle-exercises-without-neck-or-back-strain/)